# Xpath value between nodes

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find out value between xpath nodes. I have tried my best but not able to target that value using Xpath.

```html
<span class="passwordmessage" id="PasswordMessage" name="PasswordMessage"></span>
<br class="">
<br class="">
<span class="">The users new password is: </span>
"7b8rzyx
            
   "
<br class="">
```

I want to capture **7b8rzyx** value from code.
I have tried:
following-sibling::node(), preceding-sibling::br but just couldn't get it.

any help is appreciated !

[EDIT]
so far I have reached:
//span[@class='passwordmessage']/following-sibling::node()[(preceding-sibling::span)and not(self::span)][4]

do you guys think, there is any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Selenium, you cannot use the xpath syntax to get the text directly.

But this can be easily resolved by using the page source and JAVA. Strings

```
// get the page source and remove all spaces
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource().replace(" ", "");

// split the page source into 2 based on the text and use the second
// part. This will give the required text plus the additional HTML
pageSource = pageSource.split("<span>The users new password is: </span>".replace(" ", ""))[1];

// split again using the <br/> to get the required text
pageSource = pageSource.split("<br/>")[0];

System.out.println(pageSource.trim());
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: so far only this option worked for me. thanks a ton. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that code is in some `div` tag (or any other tag for that matter), like this below:

```
<div class="something">
    <span class="passwordmessage" id="PasswordMessage" name="PasswordMessage"></span>
    <br class="">
    <br class="">
    <span class="">The users new password is: </span>
    "7b8rzyx

                "
    <br class="">
</div>
```

Do this:

```
String firstText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='something']")).getText();
String firstChildText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='something']/span[2]")).getText();
String firstText = firstText.replace(firstChildText, "");
```

Comment: If I try to capture div, then it will give me more text. which is more than I required. and just by targeting span it give me null.

Comment: @Rajesh - Could you provide the complete HTML or some more HTML above and below the HTML you've provided? You can add it in the question or paste it here using gist.github.com

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b38899d5e3fbe51fa86e there you go. I hope that is what you asked.

Comment: @Rajesh - Is the complete HTML which you've provided in a `div` tag?

Answer (score 1):

suppose  that there is an upper element:

xpath:

```
//div[@class='something']/child::text()
```

Comment: @Mehsum it returns null.

Comment: sorry, get wrong element. it should be upper element.